# How can I calculate and print the colours in between in Python 3

Tags: python

I am a beginner Python programer.

I need to find the channel (Red, Green, Blue) difference between the two pixels and divide by the number of total pixels create the new pixels.

I am stuck on what condition or loop should I use to print all pixels in between the input pixels.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
p1 = int(input("Enter the first colour: "),16)
p2 = int(input("Enter the second colour: "),16)
colours = int(input("Enter the number of colours to generate inbetween: "))

red = (p1 & 0xFF0000) >> 16
green = (p1 & 0x00FF00) >> 8
blue = p1 & 0x0000FF
red2 = (p2 & 0xFF0000) >> 16
green2 = (p2 & 0x00FF00) >> 8
blue2 = p2 & 0x0000FF

red3 = abs(round(red-red2))/int(colours+1)
green3 = abs(round(green-green2))/int(colours+1)
blue3 = abs(round(blue-blue2))/int(colours+1)

print('0x%02x%02x%02x' % (red, green, blue))
```

Here is an output example:

```
Enter the first pixel: 0xFFDD33
Enter the second pixel: 0x002222
Enter the number of colours to generate inbetween: 3
Colours:
0x002222
0x405126
0x80802a
0xc0af2e
0xffdd33
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following codes. It produces similar output as the sample. The difference mainly due to the rounding of floating point numbers.

Basically, you need to determine the difference between two colours. Then loop through for i=1 to i=colours. Update the starting colour by adding the difference each time.

```
p1 = int(input("Enter the first colour: "),16)
p2 = int(input("Enter the second colour: "),16)
colours = int(input("Enter the number of colours to generate inbetween: "))

red = (p1 & 0xFF0000) >> 16
green = (p1 & 0x00FF00) >> 8
blue = p1 & 0x0000FF
red2 = (p2 & 0xFF0000) >> 16
green2 = (p2 & 0x00FF00) >> 8
blue2 = p2 & 0x0000FF

red3 = abs((red2-red)/(colours+1))
green3 = abs((green2-green)/(colours+1))
blue3 = abs((blue2-blue)/(colours+1))

print('0x%02x%02x%02x' % (red, green, blue))
for i in range(1,colours+1):
    red += red3
    green += green3
    blue += blue3
    print('0x%02x%02x%02x' % (round(red), round(green), round(blue)))

print('0x%02x%02x%02x' % (red2, green2, blue2))
```